# Save link assign value as well as go to other page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, codeigniter

I have a table where user can add data in it and I also have input field and save link. In my save link, if I click it.. I assign value to input field before it will go to other page. But when it go to the other page and I echo the value of inputfield, I got empty as in null value.

Here's my code - for table:

```
<table class="table " id="memberTB">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th >First Name</th>
            <th >Middle Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr id="first">
            <td><span class="edit"></span></td>
            <td><span class="edit"></span></td>
            <td><span class="edit"></span></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-link" id="addrow">
        <span class="fa fa-plus"> Add new row</span>
    </button>
</table>
<input type="text" name="list" id="list"/>
<br>
<a class="btn" id="savebtn">Save</button> 
<a href="#" class="btn" id="resetbtn">Reset</a>
```

and for js:

```
$('#savebtn').click(function() {

    var cells = 3; //number of columns
    var arraylist = []
    var x=0;
    
    $('tbody tr',$('#memberTB')).each(function(){
        var cell_text = '';
        for(var i = 0 ; i < cells ; i++){
            if(i==2){
                cell_text =cell_text+$(this).find('td').eq(i).text()+":";   
            }else{
                cell_text =cell_text+$(this).find('td').eq(i).text()+",";
            } 
        }
        arraylist.push(cell_text);
    });
    document.getElementById("list").value =arraylist;
    document.getElementById("savebtn").href="<?php echo site_url('test/save');?>";   
}
```

I got nothing when I echo it in the *test.php* in the `save()`, like this:

```
echo $this->input->post('list');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are simply redirecting the page. So you will not get any value from post. If you want to get the value by post method you need to submit the value with a form.

```
 <form id='save_form' method="post" action="<?php echo site_url('test/save');?>">   
    //add your html codes 
    //<table ..... and others
    <a class="btn" href="#" id="savebtn">Save</button> //add # to href for save button
</form>
```

Now your js

```
$('#savebtn').click(function() {

//js codes that you wrote
//just replace the following line 
//document.getElementById("savebtn").href="<?php echo site_url('test/save');?>";   
 $('#save_form').submit();
}
```